# How to count the number of distinct subgroups of $G$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ denote the group of all the automorphisms of the field $F_{3^{100}}$ that consists of $3^{100}$ elements .How to count the number of distinct subgroups of $G$ ?

I have not gathered enough points to solve it.So cant give my thoughts here.Any hints will be useful

Comment: Have you identified the group of automorphisms to start with? Alternatively, are you familiar with Galois theory?

Comment: No not quite familiar with it